# Why would the iOS simulator show tab bar labels in ALL CAPS and then switch back to Title Case?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have not seen this issue during months of development, but when I made a production build in the iOS Simulator (iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone Xs Max, both on iOS 12.2) to take screenshots, I saw a strange issue:

The tab bar labels showed in ALL CAPS:

[image: Screenshot of "all caps" labels]

Then after a while it switched back to Title Case as entered:

[image: Screenshot of title case labels]

I say "after a while" because I'm not sure exactly when it happened. I believe that it was just suddenly as I was interacting with the app.

Any ideas what this could be about? Something I've done wrong on my end? Another XCode ecosystem quirk?

It's not a huge deal – even if it would happen in the released app that wouldn't be a showstopper – mostly I'm just curious.

Comment: Non-localised strings can apparently be shown in uppercase: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW4 So I suspect it's something around that. The strings *are* localised, though (the same Simulator shows them in another language if I change the language setting), and they did suddenly stop being all caps as described above, so I still feel it's likely this is an XCode/Simulator quirk of some kind.

Comment: We think this is the explanation: We had the scheme application language explicitly set to a specific language for most of development. Soon before we started seeing this issue, we changed it to "System Language". Once we changed that, we believe debug builds of the app could get into a situation where the system language and simulator language differed slightly, e.g. "English" vs "English (UK)" or similar. We still don't know why it suddenly stopped mid-use of the simulator, though. This setting does not apply to "Archive" so shouldn't happen in the released app.

Comment: After more experimentation and research by @CalleErlandsson, we believe that Apple never intended the "Localization Debugging: Show non-localized strings" option to be used with the base language, though we haven't been able to find an explicit statement to that effect. Because the base language doesn't have "translations" (just uses the source language strings out of the source code), they can be seen as non-localized. So perhaps this debug setting should only be turned on if your schema is set to some specific language that is not the base language.

Answer (score -1):

This case occurs if you change the property of the title in the ViewController. Do not change the title on ViewController and then the tab bar title will not change.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure if you misunderstood the question. I'm not asking about the tab bar title changing in general. I'm asking about a specific situation where it's shown in all caps but suddenly switches to the correct string, without me explicitly changing the view controller's title.